# Vectorizing numpy mask setting

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have 3 numpy arrays with dimensions

```
M (NxC)     # mask
y (N,)     
values (N,)
```

How can I vectorize the following?

```
for i in range(N):
      M[i][y[i]] = values[i]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`integer-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) -

```
M[np.arange(N),y] = values
```